# How do i setup a Cron to run in Magento using the M2E extension?

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.7

I am having a problem configuring Magneto Cron to run. I am using M2E Pro extension and would like to set this to run every 5 minutes but having tried to configure the correct settings in Magento I get this warning:

Last heartbeat is older than one hour. Please check your settings and your configuration!

I am using a Ubuntu server and could really do with some assistance on how to setup a cron to run in Magento. I can't find any documentation that tells me exactly how to do this.

If any could share some knowledge I'd be very grateful...

Comment: Have you tried `crontab -e` from the Terminal command line?

Comment: what all have you done with crontab node values.Also is your cron.php runnnig every five minutes.

Comment: No, my cron  doesn't appear to be running for some tasks